# Where do I find azure subscription certificate thumbprint?

Tags: azure, certificate

I'm using [Azure Management Studio](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-studio) and want to connect to a subscription but can't seem to find where the certificate thumbprint is stored.

I've looked around in the azure portal on the subscription itself but can only find the subscription id, not the certificate thumbprint (as highlighted in the print screen) below.

[image]

Where do I find this thumbprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) and then `SETTINGS` tab on the left hand side. On the subsequent page on the right hand side, just click on `MANAGEMENT CERTIFICATES`. You will find all management certificates there.

[image]

Comment: Why are there so many different thumbprints listed? (whyt not just have one)

Comment: This is a user generated action. You can upload upto 100 management certficates per subscription. Moreover anytime you download a publish settings file, a management certificate is automatically created for you.

Answer (score 9):

In the new portal, go to:
Expand the right menu and click 'More Services'
[image]

On the next menu select 'Subscriptions'

[image]

Click the name of your subscription when it appears.

select 'Management Certificates' from the menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to setup the subscription in Azure Management Studio via the "Azure Resource Manager API" and enter your Azure subscription credentials:

[image]

Using this authentication method you don't need to generate, upload and specify a management certificate; you can simply enter your AD domain followed by your credentials.

Comment: As part of Cerebrata team, let me add one comment: using this way, you won't be able to manage `Classic` resources (like Cloud Services) in Azure Management Studio. Thought I should mention that.